Android application - SMS client working via HTTP
I am looking for an application to android for working with SMS via an http server (which will receive and send them for you).
Regular SMS should not be sent from the phone, only http requests
I don’t want to make my android sms gataway, I want to use it as usual, but through the api.
Here is a classic example of working with SMS:
TX: any phone(with any default application) --(sms over GSM network) ---> base station
RX: any phone(with any default application) <--(sms over GSM network) <--- base station
What I want to see:
TX: any phone(with SPECIAL application) --(sms over HTTP) ---> any API server
RX: any phone(with SPECIAL application) <--(sms over HTTP) <--- any API server
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated)
i am reed this: Android application to post SMS as HTTP
but that's not what I need
